# Undefined function height

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have this...

```
function origin_image_sizes() {
    add_image_size( 'single-thumbnail', 636, 310, true );
}
```

310 is the width, but I want it undefined. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not understand the question yet

Comment: [The first example here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size#Examples) shows "unlimited height" with a fixed width, is that what you're meaning?

Comment: 310 is the height to be specific. If you want the height to be unlimited/unspecified, you can just do `add_image_size('single-thumbnail', 636);` however, if you want the width to be unlimited, you can probably do `add_image_size('single-thumbnail',0,310);` but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

first, 310 in the example you provided is the height. According to the [Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size), the parameters are: `add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop );`

next, if you want 310, or the height, to be undefined (assuming unlimited/unspecified), you can leave it out: `add_image_size('single-thumbnail',636);`

If you actually want to have unlimited/unspecified width, set 0 to the width:

`add_image_size('single-thumbnail',0, 310);`

Comment: Yes! Sorry I meant height. Can the height be undefined width 0 too?

Comment: @BuyTytus follow the link to the documentation. cropping was not part of the question so you should start a new question